# Moving from traditional ASP. NET MVC to WebApi + Knockout

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've just read an interesting article about how Microsoft seems to be moving towards a REST interface + client-side javascript-based MVVM development for web applications.

Although I technically understand the basic difference between the two models, I am utterly confused regarding its implications about how I write web applications and most importantly how to transition gracefully to this new model.

So, for someone moving from traditional ASP.NET MVC to WebApi + KO, the following questions arise:

- Is there a way to have unobtrusive or near-unobtrusive (i.e. minimal code) validation using MVC + KO?
- How does one go about unit testing his UI code?
- Does browser compatibility suffer with KO?
- Is there anything else someone has to consider when moving from one model to the other?

Comment: Now *I am* a bit confused: doesn't .NET MVC and WebAPI have different purposes? I mean, MVC is for webapps and sites, while WebAPI is for, well, APIs (and services and so on). So, why would someone migrate from MVC to API? What am I missing?

Comment: That's not necessarily true. It's just a different way of doing things. You can have a Web API which is consumed by any client - including but not limited to, your own website!

Comment: But, in that case, you'd still need a website as frontend, right? That is, the WebAPI project would act as the *service layer*, I see.

Comment: @AndreCalil  There is no reason that WebApi can't be used for creating web sites too.  HTML is just another media type.

Comment: @DarrelMiller That's interesting. As you can see, I haven't study WebAPI yet, but I certainly will. Thank you guys

Comment: Re whether to use the Web API or standard MVC controllers, this question (and my 2 cents worth on it) might be of use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9776126/should-i-be-using-my-own-web-api/11183838#11183838

Comment: And re browser compatibility, the only issue which I have (recently) encountered and am hoping someone here can advise on is this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442919/binding-error-in-knockout-js-in-ie9-compatibility-view - otherwise I have found Knockout to be predictable, robust and generally awesome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You see Microsoft starting to push this "single page web app" thing partly because it can provide a better user experience but largely because it makes it much much easier to migrate your web app to being a Windows 8 native application.

Re: unobtrusive javascript for validation… I would say that if you're using Knockout, you're UI and your scripts are going to be so tightly coupled even just for basic stuff that unobtrusiveness is really not a valid goal.  You can do validation in Knockout (see https://github.com/ericmbarnard/Knockout-Validation#readme for example) but it's not unobtrusive by the same definition as ASP.NET MVC

Re: unit testing... take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331789/knockoutjs-unit-testing-with-qunit

Re: browser compat... I'm not aware of any compatibility issues with any modern browsers unless you have crazy users who have disabled JavaScript

Answer (score 5):

I found [this](http://userinexperience.com/?p=633) to be a really nice discussion of the pros and cons of trying to be "unobtrusive" with a Knockout site.

Traditionally I'm very much in favour of keeping Javascript as unobtrusive as possible, and with my Knockout expressions I try to keep them as minimal and tidy as possible by shifting any heavy lifting into functions on my view model and creating custom bindings which encapsulate DOM logic - but I'm firmly of the opinion that the declarative approach itself (such as the default of using the data-bind attribute), when used sensibly, is the way to go.

Perhaps it's because my introduction to Knockout is a web application "port" of a WPF application I worked on, and the Knockout bindings of my site are becoming surprisingly close to their XAML equivalents as I learn more about how to leverage Knockout gracefully. I just love being able to eyeball markup and see at a glance the real business logic around how a view is evaluated, rather than the specifics of how jQuery or whatever physically builds it in response to some click event wired up in a big soul destroying Javascript file.

When I revisit some of my traditional MVC sites which leverage lots of procedural jQuery to hook things up, I think, yeah the markup is tidy, but going back to it after 6 months even I have difficulty understanding what my intention was with all those jQuery selectors, callbacks, and DOM traversals. I think I would only apply the Knockout bindings themselves dynamically if I had to, i.e. if there was a situation where my binding logic was itself dynamic - but that could probably be accomplished differently with dynamic templates anyway.

That's my 2 cents on the unobtrusive aspect of your question, and if your experience moving to MVVM Javascript is anything like mine has been over the last few months, you won't look back.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Can you elaborate on the things you've learned about KO best practices?

Comment: I've only been using Knockout for a few months so I'd better not claim too much about "best practices" just yet, but I've definitely learned a lot and have been refining my patterns of usage continually. I've added a lot of Knockout answers / questions / motivational rants recently which might help you out, otherwise feel free to email me via my web site. Cheers.

Comment: @TomHall: good to read about your experience! It would be great and very helpful if you could post any resource with examples on how to perform typical entity CRUD features with that set of technologies (knockout.js + ASP.NET Web API)! Thanks a lot